# How can I get my Wii online when a connection is through a sign in page?

Tags: nintendo-wii

I currently have an internet setup in my apartment that requires me to load a sign in page in my browser before I can access the internet. Problem is, I don't know how I can do this on the Wii, as it just gives me an error on the connection before I can even get to a browser.

The error happens when I am trying to set up the connection through the internet connection manager in the Wii settings. I get the error number 52231 and it says "Unable to connect to the server."

Is there some way I can get the wii to connect to the internet? If wireless isn't an option with this setup,  I do have a Nintendo USB -> ethernet adapter - this might be the craziest question ever, as I know little about how the internet connections work, but is there some way I can string my desktop's internet into my wii? (I have no access to the main house's router or anything like that.)

Comment: This might be a better topic for Super User (although not off-topic here *per se*)

Comment: Most wireless points allow connections to them, even if you have to go through a login page.  Where does the error happen?  What error do you get?

Comment: Yes, you can using Internet Connection Sharing (what it's called in Windows) and connect your Wii via an ethernet cable to your desktop, and it will piggyback on your desktop machine's internet connection when they're both on.

Comment: Another solution might be to set up a proxy server. It might be relatively expensive, but the benefits are that the server can be configured to sign up automatically (so you'll never have any troubles in the future, even when trying to sign up devices like the 3DS or PS Vita), and then there are the other benefits from owning your own server, of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  As SevenSidedDie points out in the comments, you can indeed set up a computer in your apartment to receive the internet connection from the Local Wireless, and then pass it on to your Wii.  As he said, in Windows, this is called Internet Connection Sharing.

How you set it up exactly, step-by-step, depends on what version of Windows you are using, but essentially the process is like this.  You connect to the internet wirelessly with a computer that has both a wireless card and an ethernet card.  You edit the properties of the Wireless connection to enable Internet Connection Sharing.  You designate the wireless as the source.  This would then enable that computer to pass the internet connection on to any device connected to the ethernet port of that computer... provided the computer with the wireless connection to the internet is turned on.  You would be turning the computer into a router in effect.

Answer (score -2):

Is your WiFi already open? just like the NDS Series you have to open your network so that you can get to the WiFi. I've had that problem connecting with my DS. You can also read the manual perhaps you can find the problem in there because it is a common problem with the Wii.

Answer (score -4):

Just change the settings on your routers configeration page and try connecting again

Comment: If you look at the question, you see that I don't have access to the router, so this doesn't really help.