# Connect Wii to Apartment Wifi that has Captive Portal

Tags: nintendo-wii, wifi

I'm trying to connect my wii to my apartment's wifi, but am unsuccessful in trying. I'm following [this thread](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115044/how-can-i-get-my-wii-online-when-a-connection-is-through-a-sign-in-page?newreg=cc647de8a7ce4ff0b5e1b29b6b1ff626) for answers, specifically [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/115081/291776) about internet connection sharing. I've tried setting it up following tutorials, but I can't seem to get it work.  I'm using my pc as the source, which has a motherboard with wireless and wired internet capabilities. Is there something I am missing in getting this to work?

Comment: Hasn't the Wii wifi been shut down?

Comment: @Angelos I think you're thinking of the store for the Wii. Wii consoles can very well still connect to wifi.

Comment: What exactly is happening? Any errors?

Comment: @TimmyJim I immediately receive error code 51420 when trying an internet connection test